# How to check only new commits on update git hook on server?

Tags: git, githooks

So far I use the `update` hook on the git server to check the message in commits.

When a **new** branch is added I get the arguments `refs/heads/mybranch 00000...0000 <headShaOfBranch>`.

How can I check only the commits which are not yet in the repository? Whats the procedure to do this? (is it the wrong hook to do this?)

If I would take the range `0000` till `<headShaOfBranch>` I would check every commit starting from `<headShaOfBranch>` which is not good.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git rev-list`:

```
git rev-list "refs/heads/mybranch" --not --exclude "refs/heads/mybranch" --all
```

will output all commits starting from `refs/heads/mybranch` which are not also reached by the set of all references `--all` excluding `refs/heads/mybranch`.

**Note**: The `--exclude` is before `-all`. See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)!